# Pandas DataFrame defaults to NaN values when columns are specified within initialization, but not when specified separately. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Recently I ran into a unique behavior of Pandas DataFrames, which I am trying to understand.

If we use the following code:

```
col_headers = ['aaa', 'aaa.1', 'aaab', 'aaac', 'aaac.1', 'aaac.2']
data = ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaab', 'aaac', 'aaac', 'aaac']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[pd.Series(data)], dtype=object)
df.columns = col_headers
```

we get the desired results

[image]

However, if we specify the columns directly in the DataFrame initialization like this:

```
col_headers = ['aaa', 'aaa.1', 'aaab', 'aaac', 'aaac.1', 'aaac.2']
data = ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaab', 'aaac', 'aaac', 'aaac']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[pd.Series(data)], columns = col_headers, dtype=object)
```

we get a `DataFrame` with `NaN` values

[image]

What causes this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are supplying the columns param  in `pd.DataFrame` function, you will have to convert the data to a list. Because `pd.Series` contains index names which is treated as header for the input data and when you supply the column param alongwith, it tries to look for those index names which has been provided in the `columns` list and since it does not find any, it inserts `nan` for those columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [data], columns = col_headers, dtype=object)
```

From [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) :

`data` can contain `ndarray , Iterable, dict, or DataFrame`. Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, dataclass or list-like objects. If data is a dict, column order follows insertion-order. If a dict contains **Series** which have an index defined, **it is aligned by its index**.

Because when you use series, your data contains column labels(like below)

```
[pd.Series(data)]
[0     aaa
1     aaa
2    aaab
3    aaac
4    aaac
5    aaac
dtype: object]
```

If data contains column labels, it will perform column selection instead.

**For POC**,

###### Renaming `col_headers`

You can try naming the column header as numbers and do similarly like you are doing now, the row insertion should work fine now.

```
col_headers = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[pd.Series(data)], columns = col_headers, dtype=object)
df
```

**Output :**

```
     0    1     2     3     4     5
0  aaa  aaa  aaab  aaac  aaac  aaac
```

###### Renaming Pandas Series Index

Similarly, it should work when you rename the index of the series with your column name.

```
data_series = pd.Series(data)
index_ = ['aaa', 'aaa.1', 'aaab', 'aaac', 'aaac.1', 'aaac.2']
data_series.index = index_
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[pd.Series(data_series)], columns = col_headers, dtype=object)
```

**Output :**

```
   aaa aaa.1  aaab  aaac aaac.1 aaac.2
0  aaa   aaa  aaab  aaac   aaac   aaac
```